# I want to get the label text on check of radio button

Tags: jquery, html, text

HTML:

```
<span style="display:inline-block;width:250px;">
    <div class="radio" id="uniform-rdo">
        <span>
            <input id="rdo" type="radio" name="lossDes" value="rdo" onclick="LossDes();" style="opacity:0; ">
        </span>
    </div>
    <label for="rdo">Insured drove into water.</label>
</span>
```

jQuery:

```
var lossOptionsVal = $('input[name=lossDes]:checked').next('label').text();
```

Here now i want to get the text within label tag on check of radiobutton

Comment: next() give the value of the first decadent of that element here your label is not that one. if you are using label **for** same as the radio id you can find the label same as id of the clicked radio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

here as per you html label element is next to div element so you need to go two level up i.e. require to move to parent of parent which is div so the script is..............

```
var lossOptionsVal = $('input[name=lossDes]:checked')
                          .parent().parent().next('label').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for

```
$("#rdo").click(function() {
    alert($(this).parents("div").next("label").text());
});
```

note that I'm using the jQuery `click` method to bind the `OnClick` event on the input, instead of defining in within the html.

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/8d3gR/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a structure-agnostic, performance-light way to do it:

```
$('body')
    .delegate('input[type="radio"]', 'click', function() {
        var label_text = $('label[for="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').text();
        // do whatever you need
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

```
$("input[name=lossDes]").click(function() {        
    alert($(this).parents().eq(1).next().text());
});
```

and link: http://jsfiddle.net/jWB7t/2/

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this way:

```
$('input:[type=radio]').click(function(){  
    var lossOptionsVal = $('label:[for='+$(this).attr('id')+']').text();  
    alert(lossOptionsVal);  
});
```